# Unable to generate 100 users records in csv/jtl file in jmeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I tried on my local system then it generates but only generates up to 69 users records and I gave 1000 users in non GUI mode.

1. May I know what would be the issue of generating 68 users?
2. I have 2400 users list and want to run script and save the output. What system configuration do I require? And how do we analyze system configuration per users?
3. I am unable to find the jmeter log file.

I am using this below where I have given given 1000 users to hit the server.

"jmeter -Jthreads=1000 -n -t Anand.jmx -l Anand1000-1.csv "

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. We don't know, check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) settings, [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) setup and your application log
2. We don't know as it depends on the nature of your test, size of requests/responses, number of hits per second, presence of [post-processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), [assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions), etc.
3. `jmeter.log` file normally is in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation. If you're launching JMeter via i.e. desktop shortcut - it will be in the current "working" folder. If you're still unable to find it - locate the following line in [*log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/):

   ```
       <File name="jmeter-log" fileName="${sys:jmeter.logfile:-jmeter.log}" append="false">
   ```

   and change `${sys:jmeter.logfile:-jmeter.log}` to some hard-coded path, i.e. `c:\temp\jmeter.log`. JMeter restart will be required to pick up the change.